# Using PushStreamContent to split data into chunks

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a client written in Angular 2, it hits an API that returns a large set of objects. I want to split it up so I can present some data for the user to work with whilst loading the rest in  the background.

From looking online at the ways to stream data back in a request the PushStreamContent class seemed the most appropriate (open to better suggestions). I have been reading through this tutorial http://blog.guvweb.co.uk/2014/07/02/streaming-web-api/

I have tried implemented a basic example that will stream a list of numbers so I could test it out.

At the minute I am just hitting the API directly from the browser to see if it returns any data. I get this error message.

[image: API Error Page]

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

My Controller Class

```
[Route("numbers")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult StreamData()
{
    // Generates a list of numbers 1 --> 1,000,000
    List<int> numbers = _dataAccess.GenerateNumbers();

    var response = Request.CreateResponse();

    response.Content = new PushStreamContent( (stream, Content, context) => 
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var num in numbers)
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, num);
                    stream.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Close();
        }

    });

    return Ok(response);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't mater I found the issue, my own common sense was the culprit!

My browser was downloading the files and I didn't see them, the API stream works just fine!